# error in a boolean - mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

i get an error in this code (comment in the code):

```
if (checkBd ($sql, $db, $valor, $codePass)){

    ($sql = $db->prepare("UPDATE users SET activation = ? WHERE activationLink=?"));

    $valor="1";
    $sql->bind_param('is', $valor, $codePass);

    $sql->execute();

    $sql->bind_result($valor, $codePass); //Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_result() [mysqli-stmt.bind-result]: Number of bind variables doesn't match number of fields in prepared statement 

    if ($sql->fetch()) {
        header("location: index.php");
        return true;
    }
    else {
        echo "no";
        return false;
    }
$sql->close();
$db->close();
}
```

what is the possible problem in the script? an another question, is this way correct to update a boolean?

thanks

Comment: WHERE =? ... where what? Your SQL statement doesn't look valid to me

Comment: Also, you do not need to (should not) enclose your variables in `bind_param` in quotes.

Comment: code updated, WHERE activationLink=?

Comment: to simplify the question, how i can update a boolean with mysqli?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot retrieve a result from an UPDATE query.

solved with

```
    if (checkBd ($sql, $db, $codePass)){

    $valor=1;
    ($sql = $db->prepare("UPDATE users SET activation=? WHERE activationLink=?"));

    $sql->bind_param('is', $valor, $codePass);

    $sql->execute();
    header("location: index.php");
    return true;
}
else {
    echo "no";
    return false;
}
$sql->close();
$db->close();
```

Comment: Beat me to it. I was going to say, in this case you don't need to bind_result as you're updating your database and not selecting anything.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the quotes around your variables as they're not needed.

If $valor is = 1 always you probably want to pass it as an integer.

```
$sql->bind_param('is', $valor, $codePass);
```

Comment: i do the changes that you suggest but i still have one warning. Please see my post update. Thanks